# jQuery UI Tabs dynamically adding tabs and content not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I can't get jQuery UI tabs to work when dynamically adding tabs and content.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var count = 1;
$('#addspan').click(function() {
    $('#wrap').append('<span id="page' + count + '">testing</span>');
    $('#wrap').find('ul').append('<li><a href="#page' + count + '">' + count + '</a></li>');
    count++;
    $('#wrap').tabs();
});
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/qKBUu/1/

You can see that newly created content is not showing in it's respected tabs. All content is showing at once and tabs are not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $(function(){
        var count = 1;

        $('#addspan').click(function() {
            $('#wrap').append('<span id="page' + count + '">testing</span>');
            $('#wrap').find('ul').append('<li><a href="#page' + count + '">' + count + '</a></li>');
            count++;
            var selIndex = $( "#wrap" ).tabs( "option", "selected" );
            $('#wrap').tabs("destroy").tabs({selected: selIndex});
        });
    });
```

Alternative:

Try $().tabs("add", options...)

e.g:

```
$(function(){
            var count = 1;
            $('#wrap').tabs();
            $('#addspan').click(function() {
                $('#wrap').append('<span id="page' + count + '">testing</span>');
                //$('#wrap').find('ul').append('<li><a href="#page' + count + '">' + count + '</a></li>');
                $('#wrap').tabs("add","#page" + count, count);
                count++;
            });
        });
```

Example @: http://jsfiddle.net/Chandu/qKBUu/3/

Comment: Tabs should anchors inside li. like `<li><a href="#id"></a></li>`. In your example it's creating spans inside anchor tag `<a>`.

Comment: @Pinkie: I think the jQuery tabs tabify's an element once and then allows adding new tabs only via add method. I have checked the jquery.ui.tabs source and looks like there is a _create method and that is called only when the tabs are initially called. I don't have much insight into the widgets extension of jQuery. The only other option is to destroy the tabs and create again. Check my updated post.

Comment: jqueryui 1.9 changed api, add method is deprecated: http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-add-and-remove-methods-and-events-use-refresh-method